# Can we have "has had + past participle" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Can we have following structure in English sentence - Has had + Past Participle? Can somebody shade some lights on it? I mean why author didn't write - **aspect of which had conferred**

"Dickie thus arrives at a position in which a succinct formulation of the institutional theory of art is available: “A work of art in the classificatory sense is (a) an artifact; (b) a set of the aspects of which **has had conferred** upon it the status of candidate for appreciation by some person or persons acting on behalf of a certain social institution (the art world)” (Dickie, 1993, p. 212)."

Source- I got these lines from a textbook on art theory.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this often cited sentence, Dickie has not invented a new analytic tense in English, but is using a pseudo-passive construction you've found difficult to parse. Perhaps this parody will help:

> This sentence has had conferred upon it the status of candidate for the most poorly styled use of the passive by a champion of readers everywhere (me).

Or even simpler and thus even sillier:

> This chair has had applied to it a coat of blue paint by my uncle.

Comment: you are a genius. I sincerely and truly mean it.  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You have my sympathy. Some of this art theory you're been having to read is really opaque.

Comment: I've found two definitions of 'pseudo-passive', neither of which fits here.

Comment: See if you like this one better: http://www.academia.edu/12713214/Have_and_Get_Pseudo-passive_constructions_-_Collostructional_analysis

Comment: I don't always agree with you but I'll second @krishekesi, that's genious...

Comment: I don't know if I am violating the forum's rules but my head is spinning just thinking how much things you all know. I am assuming you guys are some top academics at top universities. "Pseduo-passive"... as if an average Joe like me would know this term :)